# How to import Nuxt 3 composables like useFetch in Storybook with vite?

Tags: eslint, vite, storybook, nuxt3

I am using `unplugin-auto-import/vite` My idea is to import `nuxt/app` useFetch somehow but I didn't figure out how I can do it. I wonder if there is some ready-to-use nuxt 3 preset.

##### .storybook/main.js

```
import { mergeConfig } from 'vite'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import AutoImport from 'unplugin-auto-import/vite';

export default {
  stories: [
    '../components/**/*.stories.mdx',
    '../components/**/*.stories.@(js|ts)',
  ],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions',
  ],
  framework: {
    name: '@storybook/vue3-vite',
    options: {},
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: 'tag',
  },

  async viteFinal(baseConfig) {
    const userConfig = {
      plugins: [
        AutoImport({
          imports: [
            'vue',
            'vue-router',

            // Here I tried to use @vueuse/core useFetch
            // But it's different from nuxt composable useFetch
            // And it didn't fit my requirements
            {
              '@vueuse/core': [
                'useFetch', 
              ],
            },
          ],
          dirs: [
            './composables/*',
            './utils',
          ],
          vueTemplate: true,
        }),
      ],
    }

    return mergeConfig(baseConfig, userConfig)
  }
}
```

I've tried to use `storybook-addon-nuxt` but it wont start because of `vite-plugin-eslint` bug. (refer to this issue) https://github.com/storybookjs/builder-vite/issues/535

```
[vite] Internal server error: No ESLint configuration found in /virtual:/@storybook/builder-vite.
```